# Is it safe to update existing author field in jv_snapshot in Javers?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, javers

We are currently using emails as the value for author in Javers (Spring Boot + MongoDB).

We are planning on switching to using UID instead of email for the author field. We are also planning on migrating the existing author data to use UID instead of email.

Is it safe to migrate the existing data in author field for existing Javers snapshots?